# Finding an exact "phrase" with a given string (as typed/in order)

Tags: php

```
<?php
    function filterExactPhrase($input, $phrase)
    {
        $phrase = explode("\t", $phrase);
        $phrases = count($phrase);
        
        for($i = 0; $i < $phrases;)
        {
            if(preg_match("/(" . $phrase[$i] . ")\b/", $input))
            {
                $out[] = ['INPUT' => $input, 'FOUND' => 1,
                'VALUEofFOUND' => $phrase[$i]];
            } else {
                $out[] = 'Not found';
            }
            $i++;
        }
        print_r($out);
    } //end function

    $this->filterExactPhrase("this is a test, foobar", "foobar");
```

Calling the function like this yields

> Array ( [0] => Array ( [INPUT] => this is a test, foobar [FOUND] => 1 [VALUEofFOUND] => foobar ) )

Giving the function `foo` as `$input` instead of `foobar` yields

> ```
> $this->filterExactPhrase("this is a test, foo", "foobar");
> ```
>
> Array ( [0] => Not found )

I thought this was quite interesting to find as I was looking for a solution to find a very specific phrase with spaces, in a extensively long, log file to remove from it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically, Alex has already made some good suggestions (especially the bit about using `\b`). However, your function will fail in certain cases like this one:

```
//looking for chars like *, +, ? and such
filterExactPhrase("some *markdown* string", "*markdown*");
```

The string *could* contain special regex chars (`. \ + * ? [ ^ ] $ ( ) { } = ! < > | : -`), or the delimiter you use:

```
//this is operator error (regex + markup don't mix)
filterExactPhrase('<h1>foobar</h1>', '</h1>');
```

Yes, it's evil, but people still seem hellbent on using regex's to consume markup, so your code should *either* check and throw an exception if it's used to do that, or you should defend against it. The example above will generate an error, because the string `</h1>` is concatenated into the regex raw, so you end up with this:

```
/\b(</h1>)\b/
/\b(</ -> faulty regex
hi>\b/ -> unknown and invalid flags
```

Another thing to think of is that people, once they find out the function uses a regex, will start passing regular expressions instead of a string to it. Kind of like people entering SQL wildcards in search forms (stuff like `foo%`).

```
filterExactPhrase("some string with words and 123 numbers", "[\w\d]+");
```

So how do you go about this? simple: [`preg_quote`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-quote.php) filters the input for you, and escapes whatever chars need escaping. Basically, all I'm trying to say is change this:

```
$numFound = preg_match_all("/\b(" . $phrase . ")\b/", $input);
```

to this:

```
$escaped = preg_quote($phrase, '/');//second param is the delimiter
$numFound = preg_match_all("/\b(" . $phrase . ")\b/", $input);
```

Now chars like `+` or `*` are escaped properly, and so are the delimiters.

The other thing I'd suggest is to remove the `print_r` from your function/method. I realize that it's probably there for debugging purposes, but still: a function/method does one thing. In this case its job is to process a piece of string, and find exact matches of another string. Whether or not that data should be shown (displayed, echoed or printed or whatever) is not a call this method should make. It's not aware of output buffers, headers that might be set later on, so it shouldn't forcibly generate output.

For all you know, I might want to call this method, store the data somewhere, and send something entirely different to the output stream. In short: ***a function/method should return data, not print/echo it***
This dogma doesn't apply for methods in a renderer component or view class, of course. But it holds true for data-processing code units

Answer (score 2):

At first, I thought you might be doing some complex search algorithm. After closer inspection, I was wrong, and we can fix things up for you!

There is one thing I'm unsure of, and that is why you are splitting up `$phrase` by tabs? I don't understand why you wouldn't just call the function multiple times.

---

Anyways, here's a huge improvement:

```
function filterExactPhrase($input, $phrase)
{
    $numFound = preg_match_all("/\b(" . $phrase . ")\b/", $input);
    if ($numFound > 0) {
        print_r(['INPUT' => $input, 'FOUND' => $numFound, 'VALUEofFOUND' => $phrase]);
    } else {
        print_r('"' . $phrase . '" not found in "' . $input . '"');
    }
}

filterExactPhrase("this is a test, foobar", "foobar");
```

Note the changes I made which I'm not sure you'd like or not:

- Added a word boundary before the search too, if we could see some of what your log looked like we could determine if this is necessary or not
- Used [`preg_match_all`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) to avoid having a loop, and then being able to give us the amount of results found.
- Removed `$this` which preceded the function call. You didn't give us a class so I'm assuming it's extraneous and will throw and error.

I personally would avoid printing out an array for results, but that's the way you had it so I kept it. Instead, I would `return` a value. I'm not sure what you want to return because your function name implies that it *filters* something, when in reality it does not. You should find a more suitable function name.